# setting up memcache windows running tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, memcached

We have a application server running tomcat - the app itself is Java/Hibernate/SQL. We wanted to introduce memcache into the application. I did some research and came up with these following steps. Just wanted to know if I am on the right track or not.

1. Install memcache server for windows. That creates a memcache service that runs on the server.
2. Configure tomcat to use memcache?
3. Configure our app to use memcache - Include the calls to memcache in the application using a memcache client such as spymemcached.

COnfiguring tomcat to use memcache is where I would need more direction on. Should I even be looking at something like  tomcat memcache session manager? For the first step could we just do step 1 and step 3? Any clarifications would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I though memcache was something to manage / cache the session in a clustered environment... If you drop these part memcache becomes a classical cache. In these case why not tu use something like ehache that is well integrated? What is your need? BTW, the installation of memcache for tc server is quite clear in the documentation http://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/wiki/SetupAndConfiguration

Comment: If you want you can configure tomcat to write sessions into memcached using http://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of step-2. All can be handled by your app. You can also create a separate utility to monitor memcache instead of telnet.